# Writing formulation in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I have the following SAS dataset:

```
        A    B  C1  C2  C2
Part1  100  50  20   2  0.1
Part2  100  10  30   5  0.5
Part3  100  80  15   9  0.7
Part4  100  60  58   3  0.9
```

I have, for each Part, a cost function defined as such:

```
F1(Part1) = C1,part1 + C2,part1*P1 + C3,part1*P1^2
F2(Part2) = C1,part2 + C2,part2*P2 + C3,part2*P2^2
F3(Part3) = C1,part3 + C2,part3*P3 + C3,part3*P3^2
F4(Part4) = C1,part4 + C2,part4*P4 + C3,part4*P4^2
```

I defined/declared the following parameters:

```
set <str> Parts;     *set for all parts
num nseg{Parts};     *number of segments for each part cost function 
num coef{nseg,Parts} *the C values from the dataset
```

I'm trying to write a formulation to represent the sum of the cost functions
`F1(Part1)+ ... +FN(PartN)`, and came up with this:

```
TotalCost = sum{p in Parts, j in 1..nseg[p]} (Coef[n,p] + Coef[n,p]*P[p] + Coef[n,p]*P[p]^2).
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting it quite right. Any suggestions on best way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with the SAS language? It does not look like valid SAS syntax. https://www.sas.com/en_be/home.html

Comment: yes, I'm using SAS to do what I'm trying to do. And that's most likely why am having a bit of difficulty ... I am probably not doing right, lol!

Comment: Then give us a larger chunk of code. With some more context we might be able to help you. For instance: are you using statistical procedures, jmp or iml here? If so, you better add the appropriate tags.

Comment: Write out the process using the sample values you show.  I don't know what to make of the construct X,Y*Z.